# Why is @Inject called 3 times for the same @Interceptor?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, interceptor

I'm trying to understand how interceptors work, and I have a question about life cycle.

My CacheableInterceptor has an @Inject annotation, to obtain a logger.

The Logger @Producer method (class LoggerFactoryImpl) is called 3 times (see in the log trace) on the same bean instance.

This means it is called once for every intercept* method (I tried to remove the interceptPreDestoy method, and the producer is called twice).

I couldn't find this thing in the interceptor specification. Can you explain me why? Have I done an error in the @Producer method?

Thank you

> Interceptor Lifecycle
>
> Interceptor classes have the same lifecycle as their associated target
>   class. When a target class instance is created, an interceptor class
>   instance is also created for each declared interceptor class in the
>   target class. That is, if the target class declares multiple
>   interceptor classes, an instance of each class is created when the
>   target class instance is created. The target class instance and all
>   interceptor class instances are fully instantiated before any
>   @PostConstruct callbacks are invoked, and any @PreDestroy callbacks
>   are invoked before the target class and interceptor class instances
>   are destroyed.

LOG FILE

```
[1/8/16 10:44:40:379 CET] 00000242 id=         it.tecla.utils.logging.impl.LoggerFactoryImpl                1 produceLogger calling @Produces for injection point: [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject protected it.tecla.utils.cache.CacheableInterceptor.logger, real bean: org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl@2,077,555,267
[1/8/16 10:44:40:379 CET] 00000242 id=         it.tecla.utils.logging.impl.LoggerFactoryImpl                1 produceLogger logger name from bean class
[1/8/16 10:44:40:379 CET] 00000242 id=         it.tecla.utils.logging.impl.LoggerFactoryImpl                1 produceLogger name: it.tecla.utils.cache.CacheableInterceptor
[1/8/16 10:44:40:379 CET] 00000242 id=         it.tecla.utils.logging.impl.LoggerFactoryImpl                1 getLogger obtaining logger with name: it.tecla.utils.cache.CacheableInterceptor
[1/8/16 10:44:40:379 CET] 00000242 id=         it.tecla.utils.logging.impl.LoggerFactoryImpl                1 produceLogger calling @Produces for injection point: [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject protected it.tecla.utils.cache.CacheableInterceptor.logger, real bean: org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl@2,077,555,267
[1/8/16 10:44:40:379 CET] 00000242 id=         it.tecla.utils.logging.impl.LoggerFactoryImpl                1 produceLogger logger name from bean class
[1/8/16 10:44:40:380 CET] 00000242 id=         it.tecla.utils.logging.impl.LoggerFactoryImpl                1 produceLogger name: it.tecla.utils.cache.CacheableInterceptor
[1/8/16 10:44:40:380 CET] 00000242 id=         it.tecla.utils.logging.impl.LoggerFactoryImpl                1 getLogger obtaining logger with name: it.tecla.utils.cache.CacheableInterceptor
[1/8/16 10:44:40:380 CET] 00000242 id=         it.tecla.utils.logging.impl.LoggerFactoryImpl                1 produceLogger calling @Produces for injection point: [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject protected it.tecla.utils.cache.CacheableInterceptor.logger, real bean: org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl@2,077,555,267
[1/8/16 10:44:40:380 CET] 00000242 id=         it.tecla.utils.logging.impl.LoggerFactoryImpl                1 produceLogger logger name from bean class
[1/8/16 10:44:40:380 CET] 00000242 id=         it.tecla.utils.logging.impl.LoggerFactoryImpl                1 produceLogger name: it.tecla.utils.cache.CacheableInterceptor
[1/8/16 10:44:40:380 CET] 00000242 id=         it.tecla.utils.logging.impl.LoggerFactoryImpl                1 getLogger obtaining logger with name: it.tecla.utils.cache.CacheableInterceptor
```

Code for Cacheable annotation

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Cacheable {

}
```

code for CacheableInterceptor interceptor

```
@Interceptor
@Cacheable
public class CacheableInterceptor {

    @Inject
    protected Logger logger;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void interceptPostConstruct(InvocationContext invocationContext) {
        System.out.println("post construct");
    }

    @AroundInvoke
    protected Object interceptAroundInvoke(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("intercepted");

        return invocationContext.proceed();

    }

    @PreDestroy
    protected void interceptPreDestroy(InvocationContext invocationContext) {
        System.out.println("pre destroy");
    }

}
```

Code for MyController class

```
@Cacheable
public class MyController {

    @Inject
    protected Logger logger;

    public String add(@NotNull String a, @NotNull String b) {

        logger.logp(Level.FINE, logger.getName(), "add", "a={0}", a);
        logger.logp(Level.FINE, logger.getName(), "add", "b={0}", b);

        BigDecimal bdA = new BigDecimal(a);
        BigDecimal bdB = new BigDecimal(b);
        BigDecimal result = bdA.add(bdB);

        return result.toString();
    }

}
```

Code for LoggerFactoryImpl class

```
public class LoggerFactoryImpl implements LoggerFactory {

    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @Produces
    protected Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {

        logger.logp(Level.FINE, logger.getName(), "produceLogger", "calling @Produces for injection point: {0}, real bean: {1}@{2}", new Object[] { injectionPoint, injectionPoint.getBean().getClass().getName(), System.identityHashCode(injectionPoint.getBean()) });

        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(LoggerConfig.class);

        String name = null;
        if (loggerConfig != null) {
            logger.logp(Level.FINE, logger.getName(), "produceLogger", "logger name from annotation @LoggerConfig");
            name = loggerConfig.name();
        }

        if (name == null) {
            logger.logp(Level.FINE, logger.getName(), "produceLogger", "logger name from bean class");
            name = injectionPoint.getBean().getBeanClass().getName();
        }

        logger.logp(Level.FINE, logger.getName(), "produceLogger", "name: {0}", name);

        return this.getLogger(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Logger getLogger(String name) {

        logger.logp(Level.FINE, logger.getName(), "getLogger", "obtaining logger with name: {0}", name);

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(name);
        return logger;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check if this happens if `MyController` has scope `@RequestScoped` or any other than `@Dependent`.

Comment: Yes, it happens with @RequestScoped

Answer (score 0):

Interceptors when used with CDI are dependent scoped beans.  This means a new instance of the interceptor is created for each invocation.  In addition, your log producer is dependent as well, so you'll get a new logger for each one as well.

Comment: Well, as you see from the logs, the instance is the same (@2,077,555,267) but injection is executed once per method